# Is there an equivalence to git lol and git lola with mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm using mercurial in *command line* and I would like to know if there is an equivalence to `git lol` and `git lola` ?

which are:

`lol  = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

`lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all --date=local`

I tried to find some information with hg log but without any success...

Edit: It would be something like:

`hg log -G -T "{node|short} - ({branch}) {desc|strip|firstline}"`

Comment: Can you define "git lol" and "git lola" (which are not part of git itself)?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks, much better.

Comment: BTW, `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` == `--oneline`

Comment: Oh... yeah, you're right ! ^^'

Comment: in your `hg log` you forgot date for Git's `--date=local`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, it possible, just read `hg help log` + `hg help templating`

## Longer answer

I'm too *lazy to read* the wall of text in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log, thus: if you'll describe in readable form each used option of `git log`, I'll find hg equivalent fast and easy (for existing in hg entities, references, f.e, used in `--decorate` are purely Git's toys)

**Edit:**

I'll suggest:

- slightly improved version of template (you can select any needed for you format of date instead of isodate)

  `-T "{node|short} {separate(' ',bookmarks,tags)} - ({branch}) {desc|strip|firstline} {date|localdate|isodate}"`
- define template in `[templates]` section (for simplified usage `hg log -T lol`), smth. like

```
[templates]

lol = "{node|short} {separate(' ',bookmarks,tags)} - ({branch}) {desc|strip|firstline} {date|localdate|isodate}"
```

probably add colors for accentuation tags, bookmarks, branch in log-string

- maybe add `lol` (`lola`) as hg-aliases

```
[alias]
    
lol = log -G -T lol
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know the existance of templating... reading the documentation I could find something near what I wanted. Still need to improve it but for now is enough. Thank's a lot !